# installed package.json with npm install --no-bin-links but facing issues when running build

Tags: node.js, npm, centos7, vagrantfile, npm-scripts

I have used a vagrant centos 7 and ran the package.json using npm install --no-bin-links. and the packages got added to my node_modules(including react-app-rewired) but when I tried to build the project using npm it says sh: react-app-rewired command not found. what causing this error and how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to the problem which I faced because of using --no-bin-links to get this issue fixed I added the below line to my vagrant file

vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/", "1"]

and also added my user to create symbolic links, you can add the user by following the steps.

start -> windows administrative tools ->local security policy ->Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment.

In the folder, select create symbolic links and by right-clicking on that select properties add the user/group.

And also in package.json file I have replaced react-app-rewired in scripts  with node ./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js and react-scripts with node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js